# How do you unclaim a city in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I built a city that used all the bonds, is in debt and can't make any money to start the game and no city hall. How do I unclaim the city to restart or get out of this situation?

Answer (score 18):

**There is no way to erase or restart a city without deleting the entire region.**

Your best option is to start another city in the region, develop a stable economy, and then send a gift of §§ to the failed city to get it back on its feet.

If there are other players in the region that would like to try to salvage the city, you can open it up to them by Abandoning the city. You will lose Mayor status in that city by doing so.

**From the Main Menu:**

1. Click 'Play'
2. Select the 'Resume Game' tab
3. Select the region your city is located in.
4. Select the city you want to abandon.
5. Click the Abandon button.

[image: abandoning a city]

Comment: And what does abandoning the city do? There is that option as well and I'm pretty sure it doesn't delete the entire region.

Comment: @SadlyNot: I haven't tried that myself, but I would imagine that it opens the city to other players in your region that can take over that area. I'm not sure if they would inherit the crippling financial issues that the OP has created...

Comment: Other cities could send gifts of cash to get it back on its feet.

Comment: updated answer to be more clear and added @MagRoader's gift idea.

Comment: @drudge Indeed, they inherit the crippling debt. It has actually been cited as a griefing technique - destroy most assets, take out 100K bonds, gift all the money, abandon city - game will pause and can't accept gifts (because those take time to arrive).

Answer (score 9):

When I wanted to restart a city, what I did was to bulldoze all the services (anything that costs money) except the most important ones: power & water, as well as garbage & sewage (to avoid piling up pollution in the process). You should then be well in the green budgetwise, so you can simply wait until you have enough money (it can be the original 50k, but you can wait for more to make the rebuilding process faster), and then you bulldoze everything else (hold 'Ctrl' and aim for roads to make the process much faster). You'll have some buildings on fire; have to wait until they burn down to finish the process. Unfortunately, this won't give you back all the used resources (water, oil, coal, etc.), and if you had pollution, you'll have to let the city stand empty at max speed until the pollution is gone (ground pollution and radiation take a long time to wash out).

Comment: I'm hereby referring to this as the "Detroit Solution".

Answer (score 0):

I just got out of the same situation and am now making millions. Power down ALL unvital buildings and raise all taxes to 20%; this will make everyone upset, but gives you a chance to fix your problems.

Hopefully, you just have an importing/exporting issue. Assuming you have a decent amount of RCI, after a handful of days in the black, you can drop taxes gradually down to 10% over a few days. Good luck!